# WSL: Can't install docker on WSL 2, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I've searched lots of related posts on here and other site but anything didn't solve my problem.
As mentioned on title I'm struggling to install docker on linux subsystem on window OS

I'm with win 10 home edition so I've already installed Docker tool box, and my wsl is version 2 with Ubuntu 18.04

I was following the instructions and everything was fine until I did:

~$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

> > gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed

Is there anyone who had same difficulty but solved this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of a real-time clock issue with the Glibc library under the WSL v1 setup. WSL v2 may fix this under the hood and you may not run into the issue in future. 
Now you can fix Glibc manualy:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rafaeldtinoco/lp1871129 
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt install libc6=2.31-0ubuntu8+lp1871129~1 -y
$ sudo apt-mark hold libc6

//Remove "-y" if needed on above step #3.
//And when asked, give "y" and hit enter.
```

The above set of commands will add the latest version of the Glibc library and put the stable library on hold, until needed to reenable.

You can track this issue https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5125